# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) using Contour in OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, jupyter-notebook, contour

So I am getting this error after i updated all the packages.

```
    <ipython-input-48-e9a9716d4b8c> in extractText(path)
     15     plt.show()
     16 
---> 17     img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
     18     contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
     19 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In openCV4, `cv2.findContours()` returns 2 values `contours, hierarchy`, so it should be:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```